# NGINX Configure Https

Tags: nginx, https

I am trying to run my application on http and https. The application renders static htmls along with their css' and js'. I use nginx to serve the pages. I have configured my nginx configuration, but the pages do not get rendered on https.

When I hit http://subdomain.example.com, it works well!

However, when I hit https://subdomain.example.com, I get a CONNECTION_RESET or a CONNECTION_CLOSED error in Chrome.

Below is my configuration:

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  subdomain.example.com;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/htmls/;
        index  entergmat.html;
    }
}

server{
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl                 on;
    server_name         subdomain.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate.key;
#   ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/htmls/;
        index  entergmat.html;
    }
}
```

Request your help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove `ssl on;` from your configuration:

> It is recommended to use the ssl parameter of the listen directive
>   instead of this directive.

From nginx doc  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl

Comment: Tried doing that as well, still no luck.

Comment: Does you provide your proper site domain when you create your certificates?